# how can I use a users input to change the last part on an iframe link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, iframe

I want the users input from the prompt to change the last part of the iframe's url. here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    body{
      background-color:#ffffff
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- im attempting to make an iframe display a video the user types into 
the prompt.-->
<p id="Video"></p>

    <script>
      var VideoURL = prompt("type the last part of the YouTube.com video 
URL here");
      if(VideoURL != null){
        document.getElementById("Video").innerHTML= "you typed '' " + 
VideoURL + " '' as your url.";

      } else {
        alert("please reload and type a URL.");
      }
    </script>
<iframe src="www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/(I WANT THE USERS INPUT 
HERE)" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been trying to do this for 3 days and still can't figure it out. please help.

Comment: From where do you want to take the user input? A input box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing a single line at the end of your script that sets the `src` property of the `iframe`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    body{
      background-color:#ffffff
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- im attempting to make an iframe display a video the user types into 
the prompt.-->
    <p id="video"></p>
    <iframe src="www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    
    <script>
      // By placing the script just before the end of the <body>, all the DOM elements will
      // have loaded by the time the script runs.
      
      // Get user input:
      var videoURL = prompt("type the last part of the YouTube.com video URL here");
      
      if(videoURL != null){
        // Get a reference to the iframe and reset its src property:
        var frame = document.querySelector("iframe");
        frame.src = frame.src + videoURL;
        
        // Output the new URL
        document.getElementById("video").innerHTML= "New src is: " + frame.src;
      } else {
        alert("please reload and type a URL.");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although this certainly works, ```frame.src = frame.src + videoURL``` can only be used once since after one use you will be adding URLs to each other. Of course he isn't asking that, just a slight improvement in my eyes ;p

Comment: right after i posted this, i stumbled upon another option. instead of using a prompt, and having to reload every time you want a new video, i'm using an input box on the page itself. I'm going to use your suggestion with the input box. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change the `src` attribute of an `<iframe>` using JavaScript and I think that is the best way of tackling your problem.

First off, I suggest giving your `<iframe>` an `id` to make it easier to retrieve.

For example: `<iframe id="youtubePlayer" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

If you have the user input stored in the variable `VideoURL`, you can use the following line of code to modify the `src` of the `<iframe>`

```
document.getElementById('youtubePlayer').src = "www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/" + VideoURL;
```

First we are retrieving the element using `document.getElementById()`, then we are modifying the source by assigning a value to `.src`.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to assign the last part of the URL via a JavaScript variable, since you won't have it at page load when the HTML renders.  The easiest way to do it would be to assign an ID to your iframe -- for example, `videoFrame` -- and then you could just do this:

```
document.getElementById('videoFrame').src = "www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/" + VideoURL;
```